# React: How do I use my consumer inside ComponentDidMount to change state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, consumer

So I am using React's context because I have to change a state in the opposite direction.
E.g.:
**App.js** *(has state)* **<---** **My Component** *(changes the state in App.js)*
I know how to do this using an onClick event. However, I fail understanding how to do this in a componentDidMount(). I created a basic example to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve:

### MyComponent.js

```
import { MyConsumer } from '../App.js';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        // TRYING TO CHANGE STATE IN COMPONENTDIDMOUNT
        <MyConsumer>
            {({ actions }) => actions.setMyState(true)}
        </MyConsumer>
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <SearchConsumer>
                {({ actions }) => {
                    return (
                        <div onClick={() => actions.setMyState(true)}>
                            My content
                        </div>
                    )
                }}
            </SearchConsumer>
        )
    }
}
```

### App.js

```
export const SearchContext = createContext();
export const SearchProvider = SearchContext.Provider;
export const SearchConsumer = SearchContext.Consumer;

class App extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super (props)
        this.state = {
            setMyState: 0,
        }
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <SearchProvider value={
                {
                    actions: {
                        setMyState: event => {
                            this.setState({ setMyState: 0 })
                        },
                    }
                }
            }>
                <Switch>
                    <Route 
                    exact path='/' render={(props) => <MyComponent />}
                    />
                </Switch>
            </SearchProvider>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Having another component inside `componentDidMount` makes no sense to me. That only makes sense in the `render` method.

Comment: That I understand; however, In my componentDidMount, need to access my event that I pass on as a value in my SearchProvider (I've added extra code)

Answer (score 4):

If you're using react [16.6.0](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html#static-contexttype) or later and are using exactly one context consumer, then the simplest approach is to use `contextType` (note that that's singular, not plural). This will cause react to make the value available on `this.context`, which you can then use in lifecycle hooks. For example:

```
// In some other file:

export default MyContext = React.createContext();

// and in your component file

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  static contextType = MyContext;
  componentDidMount() {
    const { actions } = this.context;
    actions.setMyState(true);
  }
    // ... etc
}
```

If you are on an older version and thus can't use `contextType`, or if you need to get values from multiple contexts, you'll instead need to wrap your component in another component, and pass the context in via a prop.

```
// In some other file:

export default MyContext = React.createContext();

// and in your component file

class MyComponent extends Component {
  static contextType = MyContext;
  componentDidMount() {
    const { actions } = this.props;
    actions.setMyState(true);
  }
    // ... etc
}

export default props => (
  <MyContext.Consumer>
    {({ actions }) => (
      <MyComponent actions={actions} {...props} />
    )}
  </MyContext.Consumer>
);
```

Comment: I think I'm almost there. For some reason, I get the following error: **actions is undefined**. I'm using React 16.8.2 and your first example. **Edit:** also, I used console.log on *this.context* and get an empty object in return.

Comment: What's the initial value of your context? For example, are you doing `React.createContext({})`? That will have an initial value of an empty object.

Comment: Following online examples, this is what I do: **export const SearchContext = createContext()** . i've also edited my App.js code

Comment: Ok, so that will default it to `undefined`. That rules it out as being the problem (and it was unlikely to be the problem anyway, since default values only matter if there is no provider). Next thing i'd check is where you're rendering `SearchContext.Provider`. Make sure you're passing in the object you expect, rather than an empty object. **Edit**: I see you've added that in. The provider code looks fine to me...

Comment: Are you importing SearchContext, or just the consumer? You should do `import { SearchContext } from  '../App.js';` and `static contextType = SearchContext;`, not `static contextType = SearchConsumer;`

Comment: I'm importing SearchContext and have used it inside the static.

Comment: It's really weird. in MyComponent I am doing 
**import { SearchContext, SearchConsumer } from '../App.js';** and inside my Class **static contextType = SearchContext** and then further in my componentDidMount as a test **console.log(this.context)** and **const { actions } = this.context; + console.log(actions)**; but all returns an empty value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188632/discussion-between-cedric-bloem-and-nicholas-tower).

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem by an idea given thanks to Nicholas Tower's answer. Instead of using the contextType in React, I just passed my actions as a prop in a different component. This way I could still use everything of my consumer if I just pass it on as a prop.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.actions.setMyState(true);
  }
    // ... etc
}
export default class MyComponentTwo extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <MyConsumer>
        {({ actions }) => (
          <MyComponent actions={actions}/>
        )}
      </MyConsumer>
    )
  }
);
```